# HTTP parameter pass for Angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Passing parameter for $http with angular js.

```
$http({
                  method: 'get',
                  url: 'http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
                  data: $.param({'chk': '2015-06-02'}),
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
                })
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.list = data;
                console.log($scope.list);
            }),
```

I can't received the value chk($_GET['chk']) from my server side.Why can't receive these parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTTP GET request you can not post data to the server,
Same things applies to angularjs $http get request.

But in angular js $http method we have option to pass query params, example is as below

```js
$http({
    url: user.details_path, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {chk: '2015-06-02'}
 });
```

I think you should change your code like this ,

```js
$http({
                  method: 'get',
                  url: 'http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
                  params: {chk: '2015-06-02'},
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
                })
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.list = data;
                console.log($scope.list);
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$http.get('http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',{
                  params: {'chk': '2015-06-02'},
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
                })
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.list = data;
                console.log($scope.list);
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation for 'chk' as shown :

```
              data: $.param({chk: '2015-06-02'}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get params value through $_GET you have to fetch params value by using file_get_contents because from angular you are making request with application/json content type.

```
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```